# Combine two angular controllers

Tags: angularjs

I have two controllers acting on one ng-repeat. My first controller brings in the data, then the second one updates the data. I need to combine them so that the view can show changes.

My First Controller:

```
app.controller("ProductsController", function($scope, $timeout, ProductsService) {
    ProductsService.productsListData().then(function(result) {
        $scope.productsList = result;
        console.log(result);
    });
```

My Second Controller:

```
app.controller('ReviewProductsController', function ($scope, $http) {

  $scope.hide_product = function (product_code) {

    $scope.message = "";

        var request = $http({
          method: "post",
          url: "/data/hideProduct.php",
          data: {
            product_code: product_code
          },
          headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
        });

  /* Check whether the HTTP Request is Successfull or not. */
  request.success(function (data) {
    $scope.message = "Product Hidden: "+data;
  });

  }

});
```

My HTML:

```
<button ng-click="hide_product(product.product_code.S)" type="button" class="btn btn-warning btn-block">Hide</button>
```

How can I combine these two controllers so that my view can automatically update when data is changed?

UPDATE:

My service:

```
app.factory('ProductsService', function($q) {

return {
  productsListData: function() {

          var dynamodb = new AWS.DynamoDB({
                region: 'us-west-2',
                accessKeyId: 'accessKey',
                secretAccessKey: 'secretAccessKey',
            });
            var params = {
              TableName: 'productList',
              Limit: 100,
              FilterExpression:
                'attribute_not_exists(is_hidden)' + 'OR is_hidden = :bool_test',
          ExpressionAttributeValues: {
            ':bool_test': {"BOOL":false},
              }
            };

    var deferred = $q.defer();

          // ACCESS dynamodb
          dynamodb.scan(params, function(err, data) {
              if (err) {
                console.log(err, err.stack);
              } else { 
                //console.log(data);
            }

              deferred.resolve(data);

            });

    return deferred.promise;
  }
}

}); //.ProductsService
```

Comment: Combine them in the JS. What I have is working, but feels sloppy. Also the only way to change the view is manipulate the DOM which doesn't really seem Angular like. So I would like to combine them in the js so that I can change the $scope to reflect the changes to the data.

Comment: why do you have two controllers for one view?

Comment: One to get the data and one to update it. I know bad practice, that's why I'm trying to fix it.

Comment: you want to use a model (service) to get and set your data and just have one controller display that data

Comment: My factory (service) gets data in DynamoDB using a access key with limited read only access. The key needed to update the data needs to be more secure so it's run on the server side. That's why I separated the read and write parts of the controller.

Answer (score 1):

We want both controllers to refer to the same `this` and have all their respective dependencies. We can do that by `bind`ing the controllers to a parent controller and passing down the dependencies.

```
function ProductsController($scope, $timeout, ProductsService) {
   ...
}

function ReviewProductsController($scope, $http) {
   ...
}

function CombinedController($scope, $timeout, $http, ProductsService) {
    ProductsController.bind(this, $scope, $timeout, ProductsService);
    ReviewProductsController.bind(this, $scope, $http);
}

app.controller("CombinedController", CombinedController);
```

Answer (score 0):

All the good practices are being avoided here so let's take it one by one.

1. In almost all cases there should be a service to make http calls,  for your read , write,  update whatever.  So create a service.
2. Create one and only controller for this. Before talking further,  let's talk about role of controller. Controller is basically a View Model a glue between your data services and your views. It literally should not have any other responsibiliy ( except for mapping and filtering data received from data services in some instances )
   So inject your service in this controller.
3. Move all your http calls to the service
4. Have an array or any kind of data structure in your controller and bind/interpolate {{}} your view with that.
5. Call the service method in your controller. It can be on initialization or an event. Depends on your situation.
6. What ever result you get back from service put it in the data structure in your controller
7. Services should ideally return a promise so in response controller should always do a service.foo ().then (function(data){    });

Bind data to your array or whatever you have in your controller